# Bootstrapped bias corrected and accelerated 95% confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, reporting, tables

I found an article and they described different characteristics in table without using common variability measures like SD, IQR, 25-75th precentile but
**Bootstrapped bias  corrected and  accelerated 95%  confidence intervals**. Unfortunately, the article's method section did not add any clarification.

[image]

I find this really clever since p-values can be avoided and all one-by-by one comparisons are possible by eyeballing.

How can it be calculated in R? Any table or crosstable package allowing to calculate these CIs automatically?

Could the same CIs can be calculated for proportions? In this paber, they reported patients as N and measures as mean (95% CI lower-upper).

Comment: Posted picture not readable. Please type key contents.

Comment: Thanks! Revised the table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison between bootstrap percentiles confidence interval and BCa confidence interval?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43635/comparison-between-bootstrap-percentiles-confidence-interval-and-bca-confidence) Also, see the manual page for `boot.ci` in R.